# MVC3 WebGrid toggling sort direction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, webgrid

With an ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid how can I setup the column sorting such that clicking on the column heading toggles between ascending sort and then descending sort?

Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem turned out to be a malformed column. The columnName did not in fact match the actual columnName (it was set to be the header text). This problem was hidden because the format specified a Html.ActionLink.

Changing the column definition such that the columnName was correct (and the header set to the actual header value) corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Note 1:** Using Razor Syntax for Markup and C# as ServerSide Code.

**Note 2:** The basic setup knowledge for Sorting came from [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but I needed more control and leverage than what they supplied for their simple example.

So...

> Here is the End-Result-View View for the Grid

[Default View http://cognitivegenerationenterprises.net/cgeCorp/Images/Toggling-MVC-Grid/defaultGrid3.png](http://cognitivegenerationenterprises.net/cgeCorp/Images/Toggling-MVC-Grid/defaultGrid3.png)

> Here is my ServerSide code on the Index Action (so when my page loads) *(again, see link above for more background information)*

```
    public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        // Set the defaults 
        ViewBag.FirstNameSortParam = "First Name desc";
        ViewBag.LastNameSortParam = "Last Name desc";
        ViewBag.CitySortParam = "City desc";
        ViewBag.StateSortParam = "State desc";
        ViewBag.DOBSortParam = "DOB desc";

        var students = from s in db.Students select s;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "First Name desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
                ViewBag.FirstNameSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "First Name asc":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
                ViewBag.FirstNameSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "Last Name desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                ViewBag.LastNameSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "Last Name asc":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                ViewBag.LastNameSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "City desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentAddress.City);
                ViewBag.CitySortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "City asc":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.StudentAddress.City);
                ViewBag.CitySortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "State desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentAddress.State);
                ViewBag.StateSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "State asc":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.StudentAddress.State);
                ViewBag.StateSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "DOB desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.DOB);
                ViewBag.DOBSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            case "DOB asc":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.DOB);
                ViewBag.DOBSortParam = sortOrder;
                break;
            default:
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentID);
                break;
        }

        return View(students.ToList());
    }
```

> The first time this runs, of course "sortOrder" will be null. However the pattern below demonstrates how I accomplished toggling of the "Last Name" column. Also, please note that I set my default 1st state to be Descending. Alternatively you could flip-it-around if you want Ascending as the 1st state registered when a user clicks on the link. For my purposes "Descending" works best.

```
    @{
         string fnSort = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParam;
         string lnSort = ViewBag.LastNameSortParam;
         string citySort = ViewBag.CitySortParam;
         string stateSort = ViewBag.StateSortParam;
         string dobSort = ViewBag.DOBSortParam;
     }
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @{
                if (fnSort != "First Name desc")
                {
                    fnSort = "First Name desc";
                }else{
                    fnSort = "First Name asc";
                }
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = fnSort })
        </th>
        <th>
            @{
                if (lnSort != "Last Name desc")
                {
                    lnSort = "Last Name desc";
                }else{
                    lnSort = "Last Name asc";
                }
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = lnSort })
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Phone Number
        </th>
        <th>
            @{
                if (citySort != "City desc")
                {
                    citySort = "City desc";
                }else{
                    citySort = "City asc";
                }
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("City", "Index", new { sortOrder = citySort })
        </th>
        <th>
            @{
                if (stateSort != "State desc")
                {
                    stateSort = "State desc";
                }else{
                    stateSort = "State asc";
                }
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("State", "Index", new { sortOrder = stateSort })
        </th>
        <th>
            @{
                if (dobSort != "DOB desc")
                {
                    dobSort = "DOB desc";
                }else{
                    dobSort = "DOB asc";
                }
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("DOB", "Index", new { sortOrder = dobSort })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentAddress.City)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentAddress.State)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.StudentID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

### That's it... Toggling works now for "Last Name"... now I will implement sort toggling for the other columns as well

> **Hope this helps.  Let me know if you need more assistance! I'm proud to help (if I can)**

*Cheers!*